# Can We generate 2 pairs of (key, value) in one map function? If yes how?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a dataset of userID and a post related to each UserID.
I want to count the number of posts by each user. I also want to put all the posts of each userID together (concat all the posts with some separation).

Any suggestions how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you can have a mapper and a reducer.

Mapper:

1. class PostMapper extends Mapper < Object, Text, Text, Text>
2. map() can write a key which is the UserID (Text) and a value which is a Post(Text) to the Context.

Reducer:

1. class PostReducer extends Reducer < Text, Text, Text, Text >
2. reduce() can have an iterable loop with (i) a counter that counts
   for every fetched Post and (ii) a Text variable can be used to
   concatenate every fetched Post with suitable delimiter.
3. After completing the loop, the key / UserID and, the value / the
   concatenated Text can be written to reducer's context.

After the job ran successfully, the resulting file would contain the UserID and the concatenated posts, separated by a tab.

Note: Remove all tab characters in the posts before you concatenate. Prefix the count followed by a tab and append it with concatenated posts if you want the count also in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your key in the key/value pair would be the userId.  The value would be a list of strings (the messages).  Most lists have a count property.

The information you are looking for would be accessed something like this:

var userId = 39;
Get the first message of user 39:  userMessages[userId][0].
Get the number of message posted by user 39:  userMessages[userId].Count()

Comment: Yes, I am clear about what the key should be. I understand that the value can be the string i.e. the post. But, what should i set my value as to count the number of posts by the user?

Comment: As you add messages to the list contained in the value then it will return the number of messages through the count property on the list.  I could be more specific if I knew the language you were using.  For instance, in C# you could create your object something like this:  userMessages[userId] = new List<string>();

Comment: A new message coming in would be added like this:  userMessags[userId].Add(message);

Comment: More simply, in a key/value pair the "value" can generally be any type you want.  It can be another map.  It can be a list.  It can be a list of objects that you define.

Comment: Thank you E Lewis, for valuable suggestions. I beleive the value can even be a datastructure such as an object. Am i right?